# ITV Hub stopped working on Nexus 7 2013 (OS 6.0.1)

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, nexus-7, streaming

ITV Hub has suddenly stopped working on this - don't know exactly when, don't use it that often for streaming.

It still works fine on my Google Pixel 2 (OS 11) so don't think it is wifi network related.

The app starts OK, but on trying to live stream an error dialog merely says 'something has gone wrong, please try later' (001). ITV's help is not great, simply says it should work on Android OS after 5.0.

Tried reinstalling to no effect. I notice the app version (10.3.0) is the same on the Pixel and Nexus, but in the play store download, the Pixel version says 55MB, whereas the Nexus is 40MB.

I had exactly the same thing with All 4 some time ago, then suddenly it started to work again.

Comment: The Pixel will run the ARMv8 64bit version and your Nexus the ARMv7 32bit version, therefore the size difference. Also the screen size differes which can result in different image resources being used.